# As a non-DBA user, how can I pass on scripts to other users that work in their own Schema?

Tags: oracle, ddl, dml

Here's my situation. I'm a non-DBA user in an Oracle database. As such, I only have DDL and DML privileges for my own Schema, so I can only create, drop, update, etc for tables in my own Schema.

So let's say I write a script that creates and updates tables in my own Schema (let's call the Schema USER1). When the day comes that I leave the company and need to pass this script on to my replacement (let's say USER2), how do I do that if the script only works for USER1? Does USER2 really have to go through my script and replace all references of USER1 with USER2?

Point being that I'd really like my script to work regardless what user runs it without having to tinker with it.

Comment: Why bother putting the schema name in the script?  Remove that, and the script runs under the context of the user that logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see what you're saying. So leaving out the Schema in the script will always use the user's Schema (aka Logon Schema)? My understanding was that it used the Schema that the user had set as their default, which might not necessarily be their Logon Schema.

Comment: `My understanding was that it used the Schema that the user had set as their default` - yes you are righ. Just tell the user not to switch the schema. Tell him that the script will break and will not work if he switches the schema.  That's all.

Comment: That makes sense and that is what I will do. Thank you for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if it's a production script that creates tables for an application and manipulates it's data, it probably shouldn't be run from your own user, but from some dedicated production user.

Regardless, if you're running a script in your own schema, it doesn't need to explicitly reference it. Just remove the references to the schema, and all the objects will be created under the user running it, meaning that any user can run it from his own account (assuming it has the basic DML/DDL permissions the script requires).

Comment: I was going to type almost exactly the same thing. :)

Comment: This is a good answer and I've accepted it, thank you. The only potential problem I see with not specifying the Schema is that it seems to then use the default Schema, which is not necessarily the logon Schema. For example, I've changed my default Schema to something other than my own USER1 schema and if I don't specify the USER1 schema in my script then the script will not work (since it looks to the default Schema that I don't have DDL/DML privileges to). Or, at least, that's what is happening in Toad for Oracle.